# WP and object persistence (or lack thereof)

Tags: plugin-development

I read the docs for [WP_Object_Cache](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache), including the part about "if you need persistence you need to use a plugin" - like a memcache or APC based plugin.

So, for all other globals (`$post`, `$current_user`, etc.) - there is no intra-page persistence, correct?

All the uses of those globals depends on the .php files being chained in one long execution event - is that right?  I'm trying to get my head around this, as it almost seems like there is application-level persistence; maybe this illusion is just a result of walking the scope tightrope very well (?)

And for user login persistence, is it simply depending on cookies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is inherently designed as non–persistent language, every request starts from no state and builds up from there.

WP mostly follows this, with every request performing core boot and proceeding to process context from GET/POST request (and possibly user cookie).

The typical mechanisms for persistence in WP are:

- database (posts / metas / options)
- object cache (transparently makes Cache API, which by default only lives within page load, to persist)

So effectively if you want something to persist you need to actively take care of storing it via appropriate WP API.